# Serialize undisclosed c#-object to XML as XmlRoot

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, revit-api, gbxml

I am trying to serialize an gbXML format from data that i extracted from a CAD model in the architecture software Revit. For every element in the CAD-model, i extracted the geometry as a polygon-loop. Thereby, i used the classes of the API of Revit, which are of course undisclosed to me. So now i wonder how i may add the desired XmlElements as children of classes i don't have access to. This is the schema i need to generate:

```
<PlanarGeometry>
   <PolyLoop>
      <CartesianPoint>
         <Coordinate>26.20337</Coordinate>
         <Coordinate>15.67507</Coordinate>
         <Coordinate>519</Coordinate>
      </CartesianPoint>
```

And this is the class i have access to, whereby the CurveLoop is a class from the undisclosed Revit API i cannot put any tag into.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("PlanarGeometry")]
public class PlanarGeometry
{
    public CurveLoop OuterLoop { get; set; }
}
```

I did not find any method of the writer.writeXML being able to write non-primitive types. Might there be any solution with extension methods? I would highly appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: You have two choices 1) Do not use XmlSerialize and use another library like Net XML Linq 2) Write a custom XmlSerializer.  Found CurveLoop at following page.  You can enumerate through the coordinates : https://www.revitapidocs.com/2015/2dc3e00b-c064-3db1-525a-d17e025550b8.htm

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help! Answer 1 would work, but be a lot of work... Answer 2 does not work i think, because i need to add two levels of XmlRoot before inserting my new xmlElements - and as far as i have seen, writer.writeXML is only able to write primitives, no XmlRoot!?

The answer i found was to replace the undisclosed classes through classes defined by myself, e.g. CurveLoop through an own class PolyLoop with a List.
Thanks!